# How to solve android app install error 110?

Tags: android, google-play, sd-card

When i'm trying to install or update a app from google play i get an error like:

> "unknown error code during application install:"-110"

So i add an sd card and tried  to install app, but still have the same error.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: restart your phone. If that doesn't work. You could uninstall updates to the play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Unknown Error Code During Application Install 110 basically
>   occurs due to Incompatibility of OS, If you have updated your OS it
>   may not be compatible with the hardware of the device than this error
>   occurs.

1. Go to: Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Force
   Stop.
2. Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Clear Data.
3. Settings –> Application Manager –> Google Play Store –> Clear Cache.
4. Look for Google Service Framework (Google Play Services).
5. Now Clear Data and Clear Cache.
6. Now you can use play store without getting any kind of error.
7. Now Reboot your device and open Google play store.

Courtesy goes to **[How To Fix Unknown Error Code During Application Install 110 :](http://www.techcrises.com/android/how-to-fix-unknown-error-code-during-application-install-110/)**

Comment: It not wroked.still same error.There are no any cash or data.so i forced stop and uninstalled updates,then i restarted the phone but still same error

Comment: @slwalathal Okay .Did you follow another method

Comment: read `Use Root File Handling App` above given link

Comment: How about factory reset ?

Comment: I can't download any app.also can't install apk files in my phone.So i can't install root browser

Answer (score 0):

1. Go Applications -> Settings -> "Show all turned off applications" (I do not know exact english labels, since I am using a polish version)
2. Turn on all android services

Maybe just part of my scenario will apply to you.

In my case, the problem occured after I switched my phone into "save energy mode" and after I brought it back to normal mode, all  (except basic apps avaialble in save mode) the applications have disapeared.

To fix it I have done things from the first step,afterwards I haven't turned on any Android services (I thought I can make my phone faster), but then I started to have 492 error while doing instalations, so I have decied to turn on just some of the android services and I got "-110", so after all I have turned on all android services and it solved the issue - i can intall everything. :-)