# Unable to update or download apps from play store

Tags: android

I really need help, everything time I try update or install an app on my phone , I keep getting this " error code:-110. I looked for solutions and I find them and they say you need to clear the cache for the play store app but when I press the button to clear it nothing happens , the "clear cache" button isn't highlighted or anything and I don't know what to do , please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve android app install error 110?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151060/how-to-solve-android-app-install-error-110)

Comment: I tried that but it won't let me clear cache or data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34151241/6078825

Comment: I can't install the reboot app the same error code comes up

Comment: I faced once the same problem and clearing the cache didn't change anything. The solution was simply to switch from wifi to mobile network (3G/4G) and it then worked...

Comment: Jameltheone that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Go in the applications and clear the cache one by one

Comment: It won't let me clear cache ,its not highlighted and every time I press it nothing happens

Comment: I mean going in Settings->Applications and do that one by one, not that one when that message appears when you try to install a new app